# mex file generated by Matlab-coder: how to re-compile

Tags: c, matlab, mex, matlab-coder

I recently got some of my Matlab code converted to C and it works. However, I would like to make some changes to these mex file and recompile.

So far, I have only worked with simple mex project: usually consisting of two files like this:

```
  Matlab_mex_Testing.m <--- I call mex function from here.
  mexcallingmatlab.c
```

then I can compile using:

```
  mex -g -ldl CFLAGS="\$CFLAGS -std=c99" -largeArrayDims mexcallingmatlab.c
```

However, the converted project has multiple *.c, *.o files and when I tried to compile only the ...._mex.c, I get following error:

```
  ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mex.c:24:1: warning: excess elements in struct initializer [enabled by default]
   emlrtContext emlrtContextGlobal = { true, false, EMLRT_VERSION_INFO, NULL, "ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate", NULL, false, {2045744189U,2170104910U,2743257031U,4284093946U}, 0, false, 1, false };
   ^
  ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mex.c:24:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘emlrtContextGlobal’) [enabled by default]
  ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mex.c:24:1: warning: excess elements in struct initializer [enabled by default]
  ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mex.c:24:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘emlrtContextGlobal’) [enabled by default]
  ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mex.c:24:1: warning: excess elements in struct initializer [enabled by default]
  ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mex.c:24:1: warning: (near initialization for ‘emlrtContextGlobal’) [enabled by default]
  ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mex.c: In function ‘mexFunction’:
  ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mex.c:57:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘emlrtClearAllocCount’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     emlrtClearAllocCount(&emlrtContextGlobal, 0, 0, NULL);
     ^
  ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mex.o: In function `ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mexFunction':
  /home/dkumar/Desktop/codegen/mex/ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate/ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mex.c:37: undefined reference to `ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_initialize'
  /home/dkumar/Desktop/codegen/mex/ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate/ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mex.c:39: undefined reference to `ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_api'
  /home/dkumar/Desktop/codegen/mex/ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate/ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mex.c:41: undefined reference to `ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_terminate'
  ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mex.o: In function `ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_atexit_wrapper':
  /home/dkumar/Desktop/codegen/mex/ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate/ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mex.c:50: undefined reference to `ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_atexit'
  ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mex.o: In function `mexFunction':
  /home/dkumar/Desktop/codegen/mex/ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate/ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mex.c:57: undefined reference to `emlrtClearAllocCount'
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

      mex: link of ' "ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mex.mexa64"' failed.

  mex -g -ldl CFLAGS="\$CFLAGS -std=c99" -largeArrayDims ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mex.c: Signal 127

  ans =

     255
```

I can see that various header files such as "ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_initialize.h" etc are properly included.

I also see that there is a `*.mki file` with following contents:

```
  # Make settings for ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate
  CC=gcc
  CFLAGS=-ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE  -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread
  CLIBS=-Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++
  COPTIMFLAGS=-O -DNDEBUG
  CDEBUGFLAGS=-g
  CXX=g++
  CXXFLAGS=-ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread
  CXXLIBS=-Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm
  CXXOPTIMFLAGS=-O -DNDEBUG
  CXXDEBUGFLAGS=-g
  LD=gcc
  LDFLAGS=-pthread -shared -Wl,--version-script,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map -Wl,--no-undefined
  LDOPTIMFLAGS=-O
  LDDEBUGFLAGS=-g
  Arch=glnxa64
  OMPFLAGS=
  OMPLINKFLAGS=
  EMC_COMPILER=
  EMC_CONFIG=optim
```

Am I supposed to `make some makefile out of this`? If yes, could someone guide me?

I am running Matlab R2014b (64 bits)

Comment: You can list multiple .c files in a single mex command...

Comment: I see you are running in linux. Do you have a .sh file in the directory? If so try to run it (either from terminal or from matlab using `unix`). You might have to change permissions to executable.

Comment: @ThP Thanks. That seems to be going in right direction. However, when I try to run `system('sh ./ConstructSystemMatrix_2Translate_mex.sh')` I notice that it could not find files located in `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/extern/include/`. How could I give it some option for include file?

Comment: The `mki` file appears to be pointing at MATLAB R2012a. You may be best served by generating code for R2014b.